# beg2char function in R (qdap package)

Tags: r, qdap

I am trying keep only that part of the string left of `"keyword"`. Anything on the right of `"keyword"` should be removed. `beg2char` seems like the best choice but its not doing what I thought it would do.

Please advise:

```
x <-"/index.php/front/yellow/searchHeading/heading/926/h_name/Architects/keyword/A//"

beg2char(x,"keyword")
# [1] "/in"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to keep the `"keyword"` in the output, then set `include = TRUE`:

```
library(qdap)

x <-"/index.php/front/yellow/searchHeading/heading/926/h_name/Architects/keyword/A//"

beg2char(x, "keyword", include = TRUE)
# [1] "/index.php/front/yellow/searchHeading/heading/926/h_name/Architects/keyword"
```

---

If we want to exclude `"keyword"`, then we would do as you did, which doesn't work, because letter `"d"` is part of the `"keyword"`. Looks like a bug to me, submitted an issue at [GitHub:qdap](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/246).

But this works:

```
beg2char(x, "k")
# [1] "/index.php/front/yellow/searchHeading/heading/926/h_name/Architects/"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use, `gsub` as below:

```
gsub("keyword.*", "", x)
# [1] "/index.php/front/yellow/searchHeading/heading/926/h_name/Architects/"
```

Comment: I think they wan't solution using qdap package.

Comment: Why would you use a package rather than core R if they are both as simple as each other? Not trying to be smart, I'm seriously interested to know.

Comment: No idea, it is just my guess. qdap is in the title, post is tagged with qdap, OP is trying to use qdap function. Nothing against your solution.